# Does old Professor X have any powers in X-Men: Days of Future Past? If so, how?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, x-men-the-last-stand

If we accept that, in *X-Men 3: The Last Stand* [just prior to being killed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58391/how-can-professor-xavier-be-alive),

> Professor X transferred his consciousness into the body of his comatose twin

doesn't this imply that he no longer has his powers? Even if

> his twin is genetically identical,

there's no guarantee that they would have manifested the exact same powers.

Similarly, I don't recall Professor X actually using his powers in *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, does this mean that he *has* lost his powers?

If he does still have them, is there a canon reason explaining why they returned?

Comment: You're assuming DoFP was in the X-Men Last Stand reality, just because it seems that way doesn't mean it is... this is time travel after all.  In the comic book it is eventually revealed that the reality from that version of the DoFP story arc might have just been a different reality (**Earth-811**).

Comment: “I don't recall Professor X actually using his powers in *X-Men: Days of Future Past*” — true, but his power is mainly telepathy, right? Which, one assumes, works on human minds but does nothing against robots.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite well lets not jump to conclusions... have you ever tried using telepathy on a robot?

Comment: @Daft: yeah loads of times, and it hasn’t *ever* worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Old Xavier **did** use his power in the movie:

- He communicated with his younger self through Logans consciousness (the scene where young X searched Logans mind to find "himself")
- He seems to know that Logan is close to archiving the goal, he is saying something along the lines of "He is close, he needs just a little more time" when the attack starts outside.

So apparently, he still has his powers.

Plus: in the post credit scene in X-Men 3, the twin of Xavier (which Xavier transferred himself into) used telepathy to communicate with the nurse, which seems to be definite proof that he still possessed his powers at least at that point.

Answer (score 6):

While Marvel has a long list of fraternal twins in its ranks - incidences of *identical* twins are much more limited. The more common fraternal twins usually have different mutations, but the rare identical twins mostly seem to have the same or very similar mutations.

Examples are mostly minor characters but over the years, in the comics, we've seen:
1. [Claudette and Nicole St. Croix](http://marvel.wikia.com/Claudette_and_Nicole_St._Croix_%28Earth-616%29): Both have the same mutation.
2. [AC-DC](http://marvel.wikia.com/AC-DC_%28Earth-616%29): Same mutation (also conjoined twins)
3. [Ilya, Ioakim, Issa Koblev](http://marvel.wikia.com/Snow_Leopards_%28Earth-616%29): Identical triplets with same mutation
4. [Alternate earth twin daughters of Emma and Scott](http://marvel.wikia.com/Summers_Twins_%28Earth-41001%29): Same mutation.

Billy Kaplan and Tommy Sheperd might possibly be identical twins with very different mutations but also suffer from possibly not actually being genetically related at all - thanks to the whole magic/souls/reality-altering incidences that surround their 'birth'.

So leaving real-life twin-genetics aside and applying comic-book-mutant-genetics to the movies as well, it doesn't seem unlikely for Xavier's identical twin to be genetically capable of the same mutation as Xavier himself.

Comment: What about Pietro and Wanda Maximoff? Twins, very different powers. Also very different powers from their father's.

Comment: @Zikato They're fraternal twins. Genetically, fraternal twins have only as much in common as siblings.