# Are there any non-contemporaneous items in the Logan trailers?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, logan, trailer

Is has been established that *Logan* [takes place in 2029](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/143456/3823).

And, as can be seen from the trailers [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Div0iP65aZo) and [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RH3OxVFvTeg), it takes place in desert terrain in Oklahoma, Texas, and Mexico.   So most things are old and dusty.
But, for example, the cars and objects in the gas station store don't appear to have been modified to appear to be from our future.

Besides the obviously sci-fi elements (cybernetic mutants and their weapons, for example, which in the X-Men universe are not necessarily futuristic) is there anything else that would indicate that this is 12 years into the future?

---

Edit:   Follow on question: [What are the non-contemporaneous items or design choices in Logan?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153875/are-there-any-non-contemporaneous-items-in-logan)

Comment: Prof X. says he is 'f'ing 90' in one of the trailers - is that helpful? (for instance, if one knew he was in his 60's in the first films - I'm not enough of an X-Men fan to know)

Comment: To be clear, I'm not asking about dialog like that.   I'm asking if there is any technology newer than today, like a phone or a car, for example.

Comment: Aside from the cybernetic claw-hand, you mean?

Comment: and the ability to graft metal to an entire skeleton ;)

Comment: @Valorum, yes, besides that.   As I said in the question, those technologies, as they are not really related to the date, they are just suspension-of-disbelief items in X-Men.

Comment: @NKCampbell I'd imagine that's a lot easier when the mortality of the patient isn't an obstacle.

Comment: I can't identify this phone. It's an Apple, but the back profile doesn't conform to any model I've seen; http://i.imgur.com/31ClYR6.png

Comment: I will point out that, aside from the cities, people living in those area tend to suffer from good-old-days-itis. And such are less likely to: buy a new car, when an old one works; try a new brand, when the one their grampa used is still available. It's only like 12 years, there are still places in rural OK that haven't made it out of the '50s. :)

Comment: @Valorum, that is a reasonable edit.

Comment: I would also add, that modified logos in the gas store store would also be valid.

Comment: 12 years really isn't that long of a time for societal changes. And Seeds is correct, rural areas are the last places to see changes.  At most, look around, aside from different buildings being up, and people having smartphones, what really is different from 2005?

Comment: @CBredlow:   Cars.   Phones.  Junk food logos.   Calendars.   Two presidents.   Hairstyles.    Clothing.   Prominent companies.    The question is essentially whether they put any effort into making anything different due to being 12 years in the future.

Comment: Well, I won't argue too much since this question wasn't well-received at the time.   But it's actually not a duplicate since the elements I noted in [the answer to the other question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/153876/3823) don't actually appear in the trailers.   Therefore, the answer to the other question doesn't answer this one.

Answer (score 2):

### No

Other than all the things you already eliminated (like robotic limbs) I don't see anything in either trailer that suggests "the future."

Comment: Aside from Xavier's complexion, you mean?

Comment: @CreationEdge For all we know, he is just a heavy force user. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12269/did-obi-wan-age-normally#comment22420_12269