# What can Professor X do to a dead body?

Tags: marvel, x-men

I mean he can take control of a living brain/person. Can he totally morph into a dead brain? Can he read the memory of a dead person?

Can he control someone who was just killed? Or anyone killed recently? Or even years ago?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Professor Xavier be alive?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58391/how-can-professor-xavier-be-alive)

Comment: @Jared I'm not asking if he's alive or not. I'm purely asking that can he control a just killed Sebastian Shaw, a just killed person or simply anyone killed recently or years ago

Comment: The recent *Logan* movie would seem to indicate that he can do so, at least briefly, since there’s a scene where Logan kills someone who is immobilized by Xavier, and they *stay immobilized* until Xavier’s control stops (and then fall over), indicating that he was holding them up while they were dead.

Comment: @Adamant good catch, does that really count? maybe that was a directorial error...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSEqN.jpg

Comment: @Valorum ummm what is that :) can u elaborate?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCTgcZ6ImsQ

Comment: Unlike the Weekend at Bernie's pic, what may be more appropriate for this group is a quote from Miracle Max - "when they are all dead, the only thing you can do is go through his close and look for loose change"

Comment: @Honey - Not gonna lie... This wasn't where I thought you were going with this question.

Comment: @TheIronCheek what do you mean? Is this a bad question?

Comment: @Honey - Haha, nope! There's just a lot of crazy things one can do with a dead body. The mind goes to all sorts or wild places when the question is phrased that way. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably not.  The movie *Logan* provides some evidence that his control over a person stops at their death-- several people paralyzed by Xavier drop instantly after Logan kills them.  (I've only seen the movie once, so I may be misremembering, but I can recall only one person staying upright after Logan had gotten to him.  Perhaps the claws had missed just enough that the goon didn't actually die until moments later.)

Comment: or maybe it becomes unnecessary...though I guess from the movie, he didn't have much of a control of what he was doing...as in it just him automatically doing something—without any intention

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say he could do that Professor X powers require a active mind to be able to access it. Its kinda like trying to access the files on a computer and it not even getting power or plugged in. being sleep or unconscious you'd still have active brain waves but dead I don't think you would at least not for long after death. In X3 he was able to go into a empty shell of a body because it was alive and a complete blank "slate."